# Sendkeys Powershell not working properly

Tags: powershell

Is there another way to send keystrokes to an application?

I have this Powershell script, after pressing the backtick key a console should open in the application but this doesn't happen, but pressing the keyboard the phisical way it works perfectly.

After I open the console by myself the sendkeys do work but the first sendkeys (backtick) doesn't work.

What i need is that the script opens the console by sending the backtick key.

```
    # startpwsscrip.ps1

function wait {
  param([int]$stop = 8)
  Start-Sleep -seconds $stop
}

[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'Microsoft.VisualBasic")
& "$env:C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Half-Life\cstrike.exe"
$a = Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Counter-strike"}
wait3
$Cursor = [system.windows.forms.cursor]::Clip
[System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position = New-Object system.drawing.point(509,763)
wait
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait({"ENTER"})
wait
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait({"`"})
wait
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("connect ")
wait
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("192.168.1.1")
wait
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")
```

Answer (score 0):

First issue I see is you are not referencing System.Windows.Forms and you have an extra single quote in your VisualBasic reference that can't be good.

```
add-type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

#or

[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
```

Extra single quote here.

```
("'Microsoft.VisualBasic")
# should be one or the other
('Microsoft.VisualBasic')
("Microsoft.VisualBasic")
```

"Wait" or 'Wait3' is not a ps1 method, try Start-Sleep 1

```
Start-Sleep 1
Start-Sleep 3
```

Comment: as for the backtick, I cannot seem to find any documentation ATM to sendkeys that button. But here is a good read on concerning how we might have to escape it.  http://www.rlmueller.net/PowerShellEscape.htm

Comment: I think SendKeys depends on your region-setings(keyboard-layout), so this may vary. I create backtick by holding shift, pressing ` \ ` and hiting space, so to generate it I'll use: `[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("+\ ")` . `+` means holding down shift

Answer (score 0):

as backtick is a special character, try using double backticks.
one for escaping the other, this way:

**[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("``")**

Answer (score 0):

Backtick is the escape character within double-quoted strings. You should use a single-quoted string instead, since the contents of single-quoted strings are interpreted literally. Also, you don't need braces around the string.

```
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('`')
```

See also:

```
help about_Quoting_Rules
help about_Escape_Characters
```