# Automated screen capture (not text output) of long powershell command

Tags: powershell, screenshot

Is there a way to automatically take one or a series of screeshots to capture the entire output of a powershell command? It would be nice to be able to see the original command and / or the powershell window.

This is needed in order for a government compliance team who find comfort in that a picture is more work to alter than text output.

This [New-Screenshot](https://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/New-ScreenShot.txt) function looks promising but it uses print screen to save the image to the clipboard. Another method looks very promising where they capture ALL the text in the buffer [`$Host.UI.RawUI.GetBufferContents`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2009/01/10/capture-console-screen/).

Steps to automate

1. [Done] Run `clear`
2. [Done] Run the command

   - possibly pipe the command to `more` to see it paginated
3. [Done] Hit print screen for just the command window and save to a file
4. Scroll down to the next page and repeat step 3 until the output has been completely captured
5. Cat all the images into a single image.
6. Repeat step 1 and run the next command until complete.

The other way to do it is to make the text reaaaally small to get it to fit in a single window. I'd much rather prefer the first solution but I cannot find a way to scroll a window via Powershell.

Comment: Find a screenshot application you like, find a way to automate it.

Comment: What about using [Start-Transcript](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Host/Start-Transcript?view=powershell-5.1) ?

Comment: @LotPings unfortunately that command outputs a text file when the compliance team requires an image. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I've updated the question to show I'm looking for a way to scroll a command and then have another powershell script capture screenshots. Would that be enough to remove your downvote @TheIncorrigible1 ?

Comment: is the output colored/formatted and is that important? May be do text output and then use text-to-image tool which would be easier to automate?

Comment: alternatively, you may use a PDF-printer and print your output. or use something like Virtual ImagePrinter to produce your output as image

Comment: Unfortunately they would not like that as thats based on text... these compliance issues are a real bother. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not using the built-in Windows PSR tool?

That is what it is in Windows for to capture real-time as you click anywhere on the screen.

[Windows Problem Steps Recorder (PSR): quick and easy documenting of your steps and procedures](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51722.windows-problem-steps-recorder-psr-quick-and-easy-documenting-of-your-steps-and-procedures.aspx)

> Problem steps recorder is a tool that is available in Windows since
>   Windows 7 (client) / Windows 2008 R2.
>
> In this  blog post Jump , you'll be able to find more details on PSR
>   (or Problem Steps Recorder).
>
> In short:
>
> • It's a built-in Windows tool, that
>   • allows to screen-capture on mouse-click
>   • and add comments to it

Though the link talks about legacy OS, it is still in every current Windows OS version
This saves to a .htm file that can be viewed in any browser.

Or If you are bent on doing this with PowerShell, see this script.

[Automating Screenshots with PowerShell](http://obscuresecurity.blogspot.com/2013/01/Get-TimedScreenshot.html)

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS

    Get-TimedScreenshot

    Author: Chris Campbell (@obscuresec)
    License: BSD 3-Clause

.DESCRIPTION

    A function that takes screenshots and saves them to a folder.

.PARAMETER $Path

    Specifies the folder path.

.PARAMETER $Interval

    Specifies the interval in seconds between taking screenshots.

.PARAMETER $EndTime

    Specifies when the script should stop running in the format HH-MM 

.EXAMPLE 

    PS C:\> Get-TimedScreenshot -Path c:\temp\ -Interval 30 -EndTime 14:00
```

Yet even with this, you now have to assemble this in to a word doc and the link or look at each manually to get the shot you'd want.

***Update for the OP***

As for …

> A timed screenshot could work but I'd have to find a way to automate
>   scrolling down until the end of the output.

… you could just use Sendkeys pagedown (I know, I know, sendkeys are a hack) or take a look at using [selenium-powershell](https://github.com/adamdriscoll/selenium-powershell) for additional GUI automation of whatever screen you are targeting. [WASP](https://eddytechdotnet.wordpress.com/2016/02/24/using-wasp-and-powershell-for-powerful-windows-gui-automation/) is still also and option, though no longer worked on.

Comment: This is pretty close. The reason why I suggested powershell is because I need to run the commands on windows and I'd like to automate this as I'm sure we'll be asked to supply this information again. A timed screenshot could work but I'd have to find a way to automate scrolling down until the end of the output.

Comment: Interesting idea with GUI automation but then why not just use [powershell to do the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39132975/2965993)?

Comment: Native PowerShell is not the tool for GUI automation as directly noted in the link you point to. You can, but it can / will be fraught with unnecessary hair-pulling. Sendkeys using WShell or [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys], and then these things act differently on different machines. Sure, you can do it, doing it reliably / consistently, is a different conversation. Yet, it's up to you of course. There are purpose built tools for this GUI automation stuff the above and https://www.autoitconsulting.com/site/scripting/autoit-cmdlets-for-windows-powershell.